# IO impact with symlinks

Tags: nfs, io

I have an NFS mount for web servers, I've moved log files to local storage to minimize IO load on NFS server but I've created symlinks for these logs (NFS share -> local storage).

Is this still has the same impact on IO load as if they were stored directly on the NFS share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

While the inodes representing the symlinks are stored on the NFS server, as soon as they are accessed, they will be cached on the NFS client.  The block I/O and file metadata updates both occur on the local file system.

This is made possible by the VFS (virtual file system).